# Ubuntu terminal freeze

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-12.04

When I run this command it freezes terminal so I can't send new commands to the server. Is there a way to send this command and then send new commands while this command continues.

> deluge-web

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:** You can suffix the command with an `&` to make the program run in the background.

```
deluge-web &
```

**Method 2:** You can also background a process after you've started like this:

```
deluge
Ctrl + Z
bg
```

The `Ctrl + Z` sends a `SIGSTOP` signal to the process making the process suspend and you get control over the terminal. The `bg` command would make the last suspended process go into background and start executing it again.

**Method 3:** An option specific to your command from [this](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient) page, which says:

> You can also use the --fork option to have the deluge-web process run
>   in the background and again, you may want to use an InitScript.

```
deluge-web --fork
```

So it should  automatically make the deluge-web program start in the background and you should be getting control of your terminal.